# Enforce indirect relationship

Tags: sql-server-2008, referential-integrity

Given the following structure
[image]
There's a way to enforce that Table1.id3 only can seted to values in Table4.id3 where Table4.id2 = Table1.id2?  Initially I thought in a CHECK constraint, but subqueries are not allowed.

Comment: Please use real names for your tables and columns. No sane person should use `TableX` and `idX` for names.

Comment: It's an abstract case, I dont see the gain to use concrete names.  I mean, how to change Table1 for "Customer" helps to understand the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's a way to enforce that Table1.id3 only can seted to values in Table4.id3 where Table4.id2 = Table1.id2?

It seems to me like you could just set a foreign key constraint directly to Table4.

```
alter table Table1
add constraint your_constraint_name
foreign key (id2, id3) references Table4 (id2, id3);
```

You might have to jump through a hoop or two to prevent a cycle in the constraints.

Comment: I think the more appropriate is to replace the relationships of the Table1 for one relationship in Table4.

Comment: You could well be right. That would be one of the hoops.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Table4.id4`, then you can replace `Table1.id2 , Table1.id3` with `Table1.id4` which references `Table4`.

Or you can enforce constraint by creating indexed view.